# Laptop battery doesn't raise from 59% (i.e. showing wrong battery stats )

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, battery

I am using Linux Mint-17.2 on a Lenovo z500. I fixed the Nvidia gpu issues (installed bbswitch successfully) and also fixed screen backlightt issue, so
I am only left with this battery issue.
Battery indicator is not stuck; it drops charge when I remove the power cord, but  it only charges to 59% and won't go any further.

[image]

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ upower --enumerate 
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LENOVO
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sunday 04 October 2015 02:17:32 PM IST (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    energy:              25.62 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         43.05 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45.82 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0171658 W
    voltage:             15.009 V
    percentage:          59%
    capacity:            93.9546%
    technology:          lithium-ion
```

Edit: add few more info

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ acpi -i
Battery 0: Unknown, 59%
Battery 0: design capacity 3092 mAh, last full capacity 2905 mAh = 93%

sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ acpi -V
Battery 0: Unknown, 59%
Battery 0: design capacity 3092 mAh, last full capacity 2905 mAh = 93%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 54.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode hot at temperature 127.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 1: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

battery's state is unknown: :(

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status
Unknown
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=14400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=14818000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=655350000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=45820000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=43050000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=25620000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=59
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=PABAS0241231
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=LENOVO 
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=41167
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $
```

More PC info

```
    sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/AOSP $ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: Treako Kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 2.6.13  Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: VIWZ1 version: INVALID
           Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID version: 31900006WIN8 STD MBR IPG
           Bios: LENOVO version: 71CN51WW(V1.21) date: 07/12/2013
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-3230M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10375.8 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 1240.890 MHz 2: 1859.507 MHz 3: 1342.250 MHz 4: 1338.085 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.1 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card: Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.16.0-38-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller 
           driver: r8169 ver: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Atheros usb-ID: 001-006
           IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (3.1% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 29G used: 6.3G (24%) fs: ext4 ID: /boot size: 373M used: 48M (14%) fs: ext2 
           ID: /home size: 460G used: 23G (6%) fs: ext4 ID: swap-1 size: 18.00GB used: 0.04GB (0%) fs: swap 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 214 Uptime: 23:14 Memory: 1142.1/3814.5MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4 
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17
```

Comment: I believe this data comes directly from the hardware so I doubt this is a Linux problem.  It may be that your battery is failing, or that the monitoring system is misreporting its status.  Do you have another OS you can try, and see if it says the same thing?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge yes i tried windows 10.1 and battery is perfectly fine it reports correct info there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to answer my question 
Here is what i did , Dual booted windows then installed Lenovo energy management change battery setting to 'maximum battery life'. In 'optimized battery health' the charging is locked to 60%,after 60% in will show plugged in,not charging

and for those who do not want to dual boot to windows

The charging thresholds are, very unfortunately, firmware and vendor specific.

The Lenovo user is luckily provided with a solution outlined on ThinkWiki.

It basically says that you would have to install and load the tp_smapi kernel module:

```
git clone https://github.com/teleshoes/tpacpi-bat.git
cd tpacpi-bat/
./install.pl
```

and write the desired charging thresholds

```
sudo ./tpacpi-bat -s ST 1 15 # load internal battery when below 15%
sudo ./tpacpi-bat -s SP 1 95 # stop charging at 95%
sudo ./tpacpi-bat -g ST 2 # when is external battery loaded?
```

Then it will stop charging once it reached 95% and only start charging when it drops below 15%

For reference, I did this on debian and Linux Mint testing but I'm sure it works in ubuntu just as well.